# Problem with Python nested for loop results

Tags: python, loops, nested

I would be most grateful for some assistance with the following python code that has been troubling me for more than a week now:
Can anyone explain why:

a)  The code is NOT removing the element #2 from the list named startt1 and appending it to newlist1.  Yet it is removing & appending elements #1 & #4. What plausible reason is there for skipping/ignoring element #2.

b) If the code is run once, the list start1 = [2, 3, 5]. Now, if the code is run again with this amended start1 list, the element #2 will now be removed, leaving start1 = [3, 5], which is what it should have done in a) above.

Please note that maintaining the order of the variables in the lists is important.
Also, I don’t want to use sets() as in the implementation of the code duplicates are important.

```
start1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
finish1 = [6,4,7,2,1,'w']
newlist1 = []
x=0
y=0

for starts in start1:
    x+=1
    for finishs in finish1:
        y+=1
        if starts == finishs:
            print (starts, finishs, sep=' = ') 
            newlist1.append(starts)
            start1.remove(starts)
print(start1)
print(newlist1)
```

Solutions I think I already know:
i)  a simple list comprehension will solve the problem
(ii) a simple for loop using NOT or NOT IN will also work.

However, these solutions are not what I am looking for since the code is checking if a closing balance in one year is equal to an opening balance the following year for a list of variable (employee) names.
I hope this is clear and many thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: what do you want the list comprehension to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are removing values from the list while it is currently being repeated through. Here is my fixed version of your code.

```
start1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
start1Copy=start1.copy()
finish1 = [6,4,7,2,1,'w']
newlist1 = []
x=0
y=0

for starts in start1Copy:
    x+=1
    for finishs in finish1:
        y+=1
        if starts == finishs:
            print (starts, finishs, sep=' = ')
            newlist1.append(starts)
            start1.remove(starts)
print(start1)
print(newlist1)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, is it that one should not amend/change an object (in this case the start1 list) when it is being iterated? Is this a programming error on my part?  I am trying to better understand the reason for the original code not working.

Comment: @marste I think the problem was that in the for loop it seems to keep the index of where you are in the list. Say I had a list of [1, 3, 6, 2, 8]. If it was at index 1 and I removed the 3, then the list would become [1, 6, 2, 8]. Now if I try to run my code at the next index, index 2 which was previously the 6, it now thinks that 2 was the next value in the list. Sorry if that explanation was confusing. I'm not great at explaining things, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but I think this is what you're looking for

```
start1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
finish1 = [6,4,7,2,1,'w']

newlist = [a for a,b in [(x,start1.remove(x)) for x in [y for y in start1.copy()] if x in finish1]]

print('Newlist',newlist, sep=': ')
print('Start1', start1, sep=': ')

>>> Newlist: [1, 2, 4]
>>> Start1: [3, 5]
```